# Chart.js Radar background color of background

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

anyone did know if there is possible to change background area of a Radar like the image, i poster?[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, looks like the documentations isn't friendly for these cases, I based my solution on these examples:

- https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3956#issuecomment-287080840
- https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/

My `options` object looks like this:

```
options: {
    ...
    chartArea: { backgroundColor: 'red' },
    ...
}
```

I used the hook function `beforeDraw` in order to draw the background-color behind the chart and it looks like this:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeDraw: chart => {
        const { ctx, scale, config } = chart
        const { xCenter, yCenter, drawingArea: radius } = scale

        ctx.save()
        ctx.arc(xCenter, yCenter, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2)
        ctx.fillStyle = config.options.chartArea.backgroundColor
        ctx.fill()
        ctx.restore()
    }
});
```

In `beforeDraw` function you can catch `options` object with your custom attributes.

You can check full list of hooks [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using this module from the chart.js library

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/radar.html

The documentation says you can change the color specifying it on the datasets properties.

```
data: {
    labels: ['Running', 'Swimming', 'Eating', 'Cycling'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [20, 10, 4, 2],
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }]
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi tks for your aswer, but I need to color not background of chart but area around chart

Comment: Could you add part of your code ?  a JSFiddle could help a lot.